# How to set a timeout in a UDP client for when a packet is not sent from server?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, udp, timeout

I am writing a simple program about UDP socket programming. I am using datagram sockets. I have to send packet from the client to the server. Then the server decides randomly if to send a packet back. The client has to accept the packet if sent or wait 2 seconds and assume the packet is lost. I cannot handle the case of the packet lost.

```
    System.out.println("Receiving message...");
    dsock.receive(dpack); // receive the packet
    System.out.println("Message received");
```

It works all fine if the packet is sent but how can I handle a situation when a packet is not sent and I still have this line of code existing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the timeout of the socket and receive messages until timeout is reached, as seen here:

```
try {
    dsock = new DatagramSocket();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1000];
    DatagramPacket dpack = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);

    //...

    dsock.setSoTimeout(1000);   // set the timeout in millisecounds.

    while(true) {        // recieve data until timeout
        try {
             System.out.println("Receiving message...");
             dsock.receive(dpack); // receive the packet
             System.out.println("Message received");
        }
        catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            // timeout exception.
            System.out.println("Timeout reached!!! " + e);
            dsock.close();
        }
    }
catch (SocketException e) {
    System.out.println("Socket closed " + e);

}
```

Comment: Ok, so it works like that but it throws a socket close exception. Any idea how to catch it?

Answer (score 2):

You are searching for `dsock.setSoTimeout(2 * 1000)` (2*1000 = 2000 ms = 2s). Here is the [doc](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#setSoTimeout(int))

> Enable/disable SO_TIMEOUT with the specified timeout, in milliseconds. With this option set to a non-zero timeout, a call to receive() for this DatagramSocket will block for only this amount of time. If the timeout expires, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised, though the DatagramSocket is still valid. The option must be enabled prior to entering the blocking operation to have effect. The timeout must be > 0. A timeout of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.

This will raised a SocketTimeoutException after two seconds, so you have to catch it.